# Bazel build command installing tensorflow from source

Tags: build, tensorflow, bazel

I'm currently trying to install tensorflow from source. And when I typed `bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package -cxxopt="-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` into the terminal, it simply gave me an angular bracket indicator `>`. What am I supposed to do next?

Here was the `./configure` step output.

```
Please specify the location of python. [Default is /home/jingw222/anaconda3/bin/python]: 
Please specify optimization flags to use during compilation when bazel option "--config=opt" is specified [Default is -march=native]: 
Do you wish to use jemalloc as the malloc implementation? [Y/n] 
jemalloc enabled
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with Google Cloud Platform support? [y/N] 
No Google Cloud Platform support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with Hadoop File System support? [y/N] 
No Hadoop File System support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with the XLA just-in-time compiler (experimental)? [y/N] 
No XLA support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Found possible Python library paths:
  /home/jingw222/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Please input the desired Python library path to use.  Default is [/home/jingw222/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages]

Using python library path: /home/jingw222/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with OpenCL support? [y/N] 
No OpenCL support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with CUDA support? [y/N] 
No CUDA support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Configuration finished
...........
INFO: Starting clean (this may take a while). Consider using --expunge_async if the clean takes more than several minutes.
..........
INFO: All external dependencies fetched successfully.
```

Answer (score 2):

Can it be that you're missing a closing "?

`bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package -cxxopt="-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0"`